# Pasar múltiples parámetros a la vista en Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quiero pasar a una vista mediante un ->With 2 variables. Pero no se si esto sea posible.

Explico tengo en mi Controller esto

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    $etiqueta = explode(',', $posts->etiqueta);
    return view('welcome')->with('posts',$posts);
}
```

La varibale **$etiqueta** fue la ultima que cree y quiero saber si hay modo de pasarla de alguna manera mediante un with

Y quiero saber también si tengo un error en el explode, ya que no se si esta bien el string que le estoy pasando que es "$posts->etiqueta"

Comment: Y si por ejemplo metiera index ademas de wolcome? return view('welcome, index', compact('datos', 'etiqueta')); Se pueden adicionar dos vistas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tal vez la solución que estás buscando es esta:

```
return view('welcome')->with('posts', $posts)->with('etiqueta', $etiqueta);
```

Y así sucesivamente con cada variable.

Puedes también crear un array de variables y pasar solo dicho array a la vista:

```
$datos = ['posts' => $posts, 'etiqueta' => $etiqueta];

return view('welcome')->with('datos', $datos);

// en la vista los referencias como elementos del array
```

Mi forma favorita para pasar múltiples parámetros a la vista es con compact():

```
return view('welcome', compact('datos', 'etiqueta'));
```

Comment: Gracias, me estoy iniciando en esto del Laravel y bueno, tengo estos pequeños errores que no soluciono, gracias por la ayuda. Me funciono.

Answer (score 3):

No te olvides de crear tus modelos y llamarlos en tu controlador, y luego los puedes anidar en el controlador en el return, como se muestra en mi ejemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Technician;
use App\Secretarie;
use App\Direction;
use App\Unit;

class RegistroController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $tecnico = Technician::all();
        $secretaria = Secretarie::all();
        $direccion = Direction::all();
        $unidad = Unit::all();
        return view("registro.soporte", 
                    ['tecnicos' => $tecnico, 
                    'secretarias' => $secretaria, 
                    'direcciones' => $direccion, 
                    'unidades' => $unidad]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, lee [ask], edita y por favor explicalo

Comment: tal y como dice Aprendiz , incorpora un poco de explicación a tu código para que sea mas fácil leerlo.

Comment: Gracias por las observaciones, soy nuevo y eso me ayuda a mejorar.